# How to represent the parameters of Log-Likelihood Ratio from a text corpus

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

There are several packages which compute Log-likelihood Ratio `LLR`, but I am posting this question for the sake of understanding what is going under the hood. I am trying to understand how to represent the parameters of the `Log-Likelihood Ratio` test for extracting collocations and compound words from a text corpus. For the sake of argument, say the corpus is the following:

```
>>> corpus = "Tom bougt hod dog. Jimmy ate hot dog. They like hot dog.".split()
```

Now I want to understand how to compute the LLR for the words in the corpus and find the likely compound word, in this case `hot dog`. I found the equation of `LLR` and wrote the function in Python3.x but I don't know what `a, b, c, d` are. This is what I tried so far:

```
import math
def loglikelihoodratio(a, b, c, d):
    result = 2 * (a * math.log(a) + b * math.log(b) + c * math.log(c)
                  + d * math.log(d)
                  - (a + b) * math.log(a + b) - (a + c) * math.log(a + c)
                  - (b + d) * math.log(b + d) - (c + d) * math.log(c + d)
                  + (a + b + c + d) * math.log(a + b + c + d))
    return result
```

What are `a, b, c, d` and how I can model them? Your kind help is really appreciated.

Edit: I got the equation from a book which is mentioned in the comments below. Here is a snapshot of the equation. [image: Equation of LLR]

Comment: Where did you get the code from?

Comment: @alvas I wrote the code myself. The equation was taken from Seretan, V. (2011) Syntax-Based Collocation Extraction, page 41. I will edit the question to include a snapshot of the equation.

Comment: What did the section before or after the formula say about a,b,c,d?

Answer (score 0):

a, b, c, d are extracted from the contingency table. Say, we have the word x and y.

a = count(x and y co-occur)

b = count(x occur and y not occur)

c = count(x not occur and y occur)

d = count(x not occur and y not occur)

For your example "Tom bought hot dog. Jimmy ate hot dog. They like hot dog." Suppose you have sentence as the window of context, then you will have the following co-occurrence.

(Tom, bought), (Tom, hot), (Tom, dog), (bought, hot), (bought, dog), (hot, dog), ...

Count the co-occurrence to derive a, b, c, d. Then, LLR can be computed using your function.